# Grafana behind nginx: too many redirects

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, grafana

I'm trying to setup grafana as docker container behind Nginx using docker-compose. Any time I'm trying to reach the login page - I receive an error "Too many redirects".

Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 9999 ssl;
        server_name S_NAME;

        ssl_certificate ssl/S_NAME.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ssl/S_NAME.key;

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  30m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;

        index index.html index.htm;

        location /grafana/ {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;

            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;

            set $grafana http://grafana:3000/;

            proxy_pass $grafana;
            rewrite  ^/grafana/(.*)  /$1 break;

            proxy_connect_timeout      30m;
            proxy_send_timeout         30m;
            proxy_read_timeout         30m;
        }
}
```

Docker-compose:

```
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SECURE: "true"
      GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: "%(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana/"
      GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: "test.com:9999"
    restart: on-failure
```

Grafana spams these logs:

```
lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302
lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=0 uname= method=GET path=/ status=302
```

As for me, nginx is redirecting all requests to `/grafana`, grafana redirects to `/login`, but I may be wrong.

I already tried different variations of `GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SECURE`, `GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL` and `GF_SERVER_DOMAIN`, as well as removing sub-path `/grafana` from nginx and without `rewrite` property.

I'm using `https`, so `GF_SECURITY_COOKIE_SECURE` is needed to be set to true.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in `resolver`. I've added it to make nginx up even if there is no grafana, but for some reason, it didn't work.

Comment: this is probably due to a limitation of using nginx variables inside proxy_pass sections

http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html